# Python - Increasing combinations of two lists

Tags: python, list, combinations, sliding-window

I'm trying to create combinations of two lists. List A should be increasing, or a sliding window if you will. List B is static. Where List A can have any number of values.

My question seems to be a different than what I see already posted, as I am using a sliding window on one list and keeping the other list static, so it's not as simple as every combination of both lists.

So the inputs it would look like the below:

```
ListA = [Val1, Val2, Val3]
ListB = [0, 1]
```

Giving the below output:

```
[Val1, 0]
[Val1, 1]
[Val2, 0]
[Val2, 1]
[Val3, 0]
[Val3, 1]

[[Val1, 0], [Val2, 0]]
[[Val1, 0], [Val2, 1]]
[[Val1, 1], [Val2, 0]]
[[Val1, 1], [Val2, 1]]

[[Val1, 0], [Val3, 0]]
[[Val1, 0], [Val3, 1]]
[[Val1, 1], [Val3, 0]]
[[Val1, 1], [Val3, 1]]

[[Val2, 0], [Val3, 0]]
[[Val2, 0], [Val3, 1]]
[[Val2, 1], [Val3, 0]]
[[Val2, 1], [Val3, 1]]

[[Val1, 0], [Val2, 0], [Val3, 0]]
[[Val1, 0], [Val2, 0], [Val3, 1]]
[[Val1, 0], [Val2, 1], [Val3, 0]]
[[Val1, 0], [Val2, 1], [Val3, 1]]
[[Val1, 1], [Val2, 0], [Val3, 0]]
[[Val1, 1], [Val2, 0], [Val3, 1]]
[[Val1, 1], [Val2, 1], [Val3, 0]]
[[Val1, 1], [Val2, 1], [Val3, 1]]
```

I've been experimenting with itertools combinations and product for a while now, I cannot get my head around it. Covid brain fog :D. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is this an assignment/homework ? As answers mentioned, you first have to understand the pattern you are trying to achieve. Besides, you haven't posted any code ... so its impossible to tell where you had to right/wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine there's a cleaner way to do this, but this works.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations, product

A = ['v1', 'v2', 'v3']
B = [0, 1]

for i in chain.from_iterable(combinations(A, k+1) for k in range(len(A))):   
    print([list(zip(i,j)) for j in product(B,repeat=len(i))])

print()
```

In the for loop, we loop over the powerset of A (excluding the empty set). So (v1), (v2), (v3), (v1,v2), (v1,v3), (v2,v3), (v1,v2,v3).

product(B,repeat=len(i)) is all permutations (allowing repeats) of elements of B of len(i). So if i = (v1,v2), we would get ((0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)).

Finally, loop through those permutations and zip each one with i. Repeat for all elements of the powerset.

Comment: It's perfect. Thanks. I had gotten as far as creating the powerset in that exact way, but I was missing the next step to join them together.

Answer (score 1):

Its complicated to understand this increasing combinations but once you understand it, you will feel it easy

Let me help you to understand the logic behind this

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections.abc import Iterable

listA = ["Val1", "Val2", "Val3"]
listB = [0, 1]

def perm(l, k):
    n, p = l
    res = ((i,) for i in l)
    prev_gen = (i for i in res)
    for i in range(1, k+1):
        res = ((j, *i) if isinstance(i, Iterable) else (j, i) for i in prev_gen for j in (n, p))
        prev_gen = res
    return res

# 3C1 * 2 + 3C2 * 2^2 + 3C3*2^3
for idx in range(1, len(listA)+1):
    for j in combinations(listA, idx):
        for k in perm(listB, idx-1):
            print(list(zip(j, k)))
```

This is the code to generate all possible combinations.
I tried to understand the pattern behind this and I found the following pattern in this

If `len(list1) = 3`
and `len(list2) = 2` then it will look like

`3C1*2^1 + 3C2*2^2 + 3C3 * 2^3`

So with this approach, I tried to build the combinations.

## output from above code

```
[('Val1', 0)]
[('Val1', 1)]
[('Val2', 0)]
[('Val2', 1)]
[('Val3', 0)]
[('Val3', 1)]
[('Val1', 0), ('Val2', 0)]
[('Val1', 1), ('Val2', 0)]
[('Val1', 0), ('Val2', 1)]
[('Val1', 1), ('Val2', 1)]
[('Val1', 0), ('Val3', 0)]
[('Val1', 1), ('Val3', 0)]
[('Val1', 0), ('Val3', 1)]
[('Val1', 1), ('Val3', 1)]
[('Val2', 0), ('Val3', 0)]
[('Val2', 1), ('Val3', 0)]
[('Val2', 0), ('Val3', 1)]
[('Val2', 1), ('Val3', 1)]
[('Val1', 0), ('Val2', 0), ('Val3', 0)]
[('Val1', 1), ('Val2', 0), ('Val3', 0)]
[('Val1', 0), ('Val2', 1), ('Val3', 0)]
[('Val1', 1), ('Val2', 1), ('Val3', 0)]
[('Val1', 0), ('Val2', 0), ('Val3', 1)]
[('Val1', 1), ('Val2', 0), ('Val3', 1)]
[('Val1', 0), ('Val2', 1), ('Val3', 1)]
[('Val1', 1), ('Val2', 1), ('Val3', 1)]
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. I can only select one though and other response was much closer to mine own attempt. But really a great response.

Comment: @so_usr_fivemillion we are here to help, so its not an issue that which answer you accept, but you understand your problem correctly this is what we want.